# jQuery referring to an external template script by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, external

When I use jQuery to refer to a script ...

```
var template = _.template( $('#homeTemplate').html(), args );
```

... it works, but only when the script is in `<head>` like this ...

```
<script type="text/template" id="homeTemplate">
    <div class="homePage">
        <% /* stuff */ %>       
    </div>
</script>
```

If I move it to an external file like this ...

```
<script src="js/templates/hometemplate.js" type="text/template" id="homeTemplate"></script>
```

It stops working. Why? And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see where the confusion is coming from - The only reason template content is typically put in a script tag is because that prevents browser from accidentally generating that HTML in the DOM.

Including `js/templates/hometemplate.js` will **not** generate an DOM element that you can select using jQuery. 
Use AJAX instead to grab the content from js/templates/hometemplate.js:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'js/templates/hometemplate.js' 
}).done(function(data) { 
    _.template(data,args);
});
```

Comment: what would the non ajax solution be ?

Comment: In hometemplate.js, have to add the template string as a global variable... Something like: `window._tempTemplate = 'YOUR TEMPLATE';` Then, in your main script include reference that global var: `_.template(window._tempTemplate);`

Comment: got it.  Just going to award this one as my correctly accepted answer. also I want to call out Dennis Cheung's comment as he lists possible options. Thanks adamb

Answer (score 1):

The second method doesn't work as `homeTemplate`'s `innerHTML` is an empty string. The solution is using the first *working* method or loading the template via Ajax.

Comment: How would I do this using the first working method you mentioned ?

Comment: The first method is in your question, setting `innerHTML` of a script tag.  If you have many templates using Ajax is the best option.

Comment: okay my misunderstanding, not 'the first working method', you meant my first working method in the original post. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

The `<script>` template hack, is used to include "NON-HTML" inside a HTML document. If you don't want to have it embed in your HTML, don't use `<script>`.

There is only fews ways to get a template, a string too long, to your Javascript, there are pros and cons.

- hidden element
- `<script>` hack
- AJAX
- long inline Javascript string
- yet coming [new `<template>` tag](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-template-element), (not even browser supported)

BTW. why do you want your template not being embed in HTML which introduce additional round-trip-latency-delay when templates is supposed to be small (compare with full HTML)?

Answer (score 1):

You could grab them using AJAX. However, I like to keep them organized in a single JS file like:

```
 Templates = {};

 Templates.myTemplate = [
   "<section>",
         "<article><% /* stuff */ %></article>",
   "</section>"
   ].join( '\n' );
```

`Templates` object can then be a property on the global app object `app.Templates`